# How to redirect to new screen for each dynamic grid view content?

Tags: javascript, css, html, gridview, ionic-framework

I have one grid view, and i am showing data from my database. So like say, if I have 6 titles.Then my grid view will be 6 (boxes ). Whenever I press each grid view title [ box ]. I need to redirect to separate 6 screen. How to do that?

So if I press my first title in my grid view. That is `Orders` I need to redirect to `order.html`, and if I press `Delivery` I need to redirect them to `Delivery.html`. How to do that?

Is that any way to check with id or name 0r any idea.

Updated :

```
   .controller('MydashCtrl', function($scope, $state, $window) {

  $scope.Data = [{
    "id"   :  "1",
    "name" : "Orders",
    "Image" : "http://img.21food.com/20110609/product/1306576307495.jpg"
  },{
    "id"   :  "2",
    "name" : "Delivery",
    "Image" : "https://www.wildflavors.com/NA-EN/assets/Image/bakery.png"
  },{
    "id"   :  "3",
    "name" : "Collections",
    "Image" : "http://royalnutrimakmur.com/img/productImg02.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id"   :  "4",
    "name" : "Payments",
    "Image" : "http://royalnutrimakmur.com/img/productImg02.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id"   :  "5",
    "name" : "Purchase",
    "Image" : "http://royalnutrimakmur.com/img/productImg02.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id"   :  "6",
    "name" : "Re-Orders",
    "Image" : "http://royalnutrimakmur.com/img/productImg02.jpg"
  }]

   $scope.changestate= function(name) { 

     if(name="Orders"){
      $state.go('reorder', { details : JSON.stringify(name) });
      }else if(name="Delivery"){
     $state.go('dashboarddetail', { details : JSON.stringify(name) });
      }


  }



})
```

**My Html code :**

```
    <div class="item item-body no-padding scroll" style="border-width: 0px !important;">

        <div class="row no-padding" ng-repeat="mydash in Data"  ng-if="$index % 2 === 0">

            <div class="col col-50 custom-design2" style="background: url({{Data[$index].Image}}) no-repeat center;background-size: cover; " ng-click="changestate(Data[$index].name)" ng-if="$index < Data.length">
                <div class="custom-design1"><span class="grid-title">{{Data[$index].name}}</span></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col col-50 custom-design2" style="background: url({{Data[$index + 1].Image}}) no-repeat center;background-size: cover; " ng-click="changestate(Data[$index + 1].name)" ng-if="$index + 1 < Data.length">
                <div class="custom-design1"><span class="grid-title">{{Data[$index + 1].name}}</span></div>
            </div>


        </div>



    </div>

</div>
```

Okay its redirecting . but now in my redirecting screen. the content name .Title is not showing ??

**Here my code of one redirect screen for my order title :**

My screen html code :

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" title= {{singleDetail.name}} hide-nav-bar="false" class=" ">
```

Controller code for this html :

```
.controller('reorderCtrl', function($scope, $state, $window, $ionicPopup, $stateParams, $ionicLoading, $timeout, $ionicHistory){
  $scope.singleDetail = JSON.parse($stateParams.details);


})
```

May be this is becasuse of my home grid view controller or not ?

```
.controller('MydashCtrl', function($scope, $state, $window) {

  $scope.Data = [{
    "id"   :  "1",
    "name" : "Orders",
    "Image" : "http://img.21food.com/20110609/product/1306576307495.jpg"
  },{
    "id"   :  "2",
    "name" : "Delivery",
    "Image" : "https://www.wildflavors.com/NA-EN/assets/Image/bakery.png"
  },{
    "id"   :  "3",
    "name" : "Collections",
    "Image" : "http://royalnutrimakmur.com/img/productImg02.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id"   :  "4",
    "name" : "Payments",
    "Image" : "http://royalnutrimakmur.com/img/productImg02.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id"   :  "5",
    "name" : "Purchase",
    "Image" : "http://royalnutrimakmur.com/img/productImg02.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id"   :  "6",
    "name" : "Re-Orders",
    "Image" : "http://royalnutrimakmur.com/img/productImg02.jpg"
  }]

   $scope.changestate= function(name) { 

     if(name=="Orders"){
      $state.go('dashboarddetail', { details : JSON.stringify(name) });
      }else if(name=="Re-Orders"){
     $state.go('reorder', { details : JSON.stringify(name) });
      }


  }



})
```

Comment: Try with ng-click="" or ui-sref="" on order tile and also like other make a function in controller

Comment: That only i dont know where i need to make that ng-click, ui-sref. becasue in my .html code. already i am calling one function for online in my grid view row. But again should i need to remove that . And where i need to place that ng-click or ui-sref code in my order title ??

Comment: I have given an answer.. May be it will helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is just call a function in ng-clcik as like:

In view just call this function with value which you want to redirction:

```
<div ng-click="changestate(Data[$index].name)">Tile</div> //eg. of one tile
```

In Controller create function for redirection:

```
    $scope.changestate= function(name) {
      if(name=="Orders"){
      $state.go("app.order"); 
      }else if(name=="Delivery"){
      ... // whatever your code here
      }

    };
```

Thanks

Comment: i have done. but stil its not working. Its not going to the respective screen. Please check my updated post

Comment: Please use (name=='Orders') in if condition as like my answer.

Comment: yes, its worked. But new bug in my redirect screen.Please see my updated post

Comment: Ha ha ha.. you want to resolve all code from start to end... its ok.. Please just console.log($stateParams.details); in controller .. you will get your answer.

Comment: i mean. When i press order title it will redirect to one screen.And in that screen,My title i need to show as `ORDER`.Thats why i have showed my code.How i am calling.So can  pass both name,orderDetail, in same function. Because initially i use to call ` $state.go('reorder', { details : JSON.stringify(orderDetail) });`.

Comment: try with this :  $state.go('reorder', { details : JSON.stringify(orderDetail), title:'xxxx' }); and call direct title on page

Comment: I did like this 1$scope.changestate= function(name) { 

     if(name=="Orders"){
      $state.go('dashboarddetail', { details : JSON.stringify(orderDetail) });
      }else if(name=="Re-Orders"){
     $state.go('reorder', { details : JSON.stringify(orderDetail) });
      }


  }`

Comment: But in function i am passing one parameters as name, orderDetail i din pass know. Then how can i use `details : JSON.stringify(orderDetail`

Comment: Any solution ??

Comment: Thanks.. i hope.. you will get your answer

Comment: can you please help me for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496455/how-to-show-pdf-file-in-ionic-app-with-out-download