# how to show pdf file in ionic app with out download

Tags: html, angularjs, pdf, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Things i did :

1. used inappbrowser
2. used google doc
3. used webview

so i have tried all these methods to show the pdf file in android device using ionic. But no use, i can see the download button in all these methods. Can any one tell me how can i display pdf without download option for user.

my code :

```
 <div  class="col col-50 clsGrid" ng-click="showFile('http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf')">
</div>
```

my pdf file :

**http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf**

**My JS :**

```
$scope.showModal = function(templateUrl) {
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(templateUrl, {
            scope: $scope,
            animation: 'slide-in-up'
        }).then(function(modal) {
            $ionicLoading.show({
            duration: 1000
});
            $scope.modal = modal;
            $scope.modal.show();
        });
    }

    // Close the modal
    $scope.closeModal = function() {
        $scope.modal.hide();
        $scope.modal.remove()
    };

    $scope.showFile = function(FileUrl) {
        var file = FileUrl;
        console.log(file);
        //var openurl = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(file, '_blank');
      //  var openurl = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(file,'_blank', 'location=yes');

          // var openurl = cordova.InAppBrowser.open("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + file, '_blank');

    // var openurl = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf&embedded=true', '_blank');

          //window.open("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf&embedded=true",'_blank');


    var openurl = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf&embedded=true&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0', '_blank');



      }
```

I tried all ways. But not able to find the solution.If any one know it will be usefull.If any expert in this, i can send my demo project for reference .
Thanks in advance !

Comment: what happen with in app browser issue

Comment: @KumarRakesh   my pdf is not showing in webview. But if i open in browser, chrome, default pdf view its opening. But i dont want download button . Means that my pdf is for viewing , not for download for user

Comment: Ok... you should open this file in GOOGLE DOCS view. Where user can download it.

Comment: yes i tried that also. but in google doc also . download option is available.

Comment: I tried this code `// var openurl = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf&embedded=true', '_blank');` but at top corner i can see `pop out` button to download the pdf

Comment: so i should not allow user to download the pdf from my app

Comment: http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-open-a-file-using-its-default-application-in-ionic-framework/

Comment: @KumarRakesh  shall i sent my project to you. i tried all . but nothing worked. Please help me out  ??

Comment: @Edison   i tried the link what you haev sent me. But its not working in device . I downloaded the project from github.Shall i share my project zip.? Can you please help me out ???

Comment: @Edison  i done like that same tutorials . But its not working

Comment: https://github.com/winkerVSbecks/angular-pdf-viewer  ,https://github.com/akrennmair/ng-pdfviewer

Comment: @Edison  i saw this. But i dont see any demo project that they have used in it.

Comment: And also i din understand how can i pass my url to it to show the pdf without download

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44182341/6001315 Hope this could help you.

Comment: **I tried this code working me my project**

 **view pdf file in InAppBrowser use**
 `this.iab.create('https://docs.google.com/viewer?url='+this.url+'&embedded=true', '_system');`
 
**Download pdf file**
`window.open(this.url, '_system', 'location=yes');`

Answer (score 1):

**You will need to use [`ng-pdfviewer`](https://github.com/akrennmair/ng-pdfviewer).**

AngularJS PDF viewer directive using pdf.js.

```
<button ng-click="prevPage()">&lt;</button>
<button ng-click="nextPage()">&gt;</button>
<br>
<span>{{currentPage}}/{{totalPages}}</span>
<br>
<pdfviewer src="test.pdf" on-page-load='pageLoaded(page,total)' id="viewer"></pdfviewer>
```

and in your AngularJS code:

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', [ 'ngPDFViewer' ]);

app.controller('TestCtrl', [ '$scope', 'PDFViewerService', function($scope, pdf) {
    $scope.viewer = pdf.Instance("viewer");

    $scope.nextPage = function() {
        $scope.viewer.nextPage();
    };

    $scope.prevPage = function() {
        $scope.viewer.prevPage();
    };

    $scope.pageLoaded = function(curPage, totalPages) {
        $scope.currentPage = curPage;
        $scope.totalPages = totalPages;
    };
}]);
```