# Typescript Error ';' expected. ionic 2

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on navigate from one page to another page in ionci 2. I have two question. Now i am doing push from one screen to another screen with back button.

But how can i do with model screen when i navigate from one screen to another screen.

And i am getting this `Typescript Error
';' expected.` error when i put this code for push screen from one page to another screen:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

 goToSomethingElse() {
    this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
}

  }
```

**My html**

```
 <button class="button footerbtnone" (click)="goToSomethingElse()">LOG IN</button>
```

Please help me out.Thanks !

**My full .js :**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

  slideData = [{ image: "assets/images/l1.png" },{ image: "assets/images/l2.png" },{ image: "assets/images/l3.png" }]


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

 goToSomethingElse() {
    this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
}

  }

}
```

Comment: Unmatched parentheses. That's all.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi  Measn that. I am new to handle ionic 2 first time. Please explain me how to solve this

Comment: function definition inside constructor? Its not related to ionic or angular, even mobile app. Its just javascript concept

Comment: i saw some tutorial here https://alligator.io/ionic/navigating-passing-data-ionic/ . then how can i write onclick method in html and in controller to perfomr redirection from one screen to another screen

Comment: @PriyeshKumar  i have updated my full controller code in my post. If i want to perform redirection from one screen to another screen. How can i write in my html and controller to do that

Comment: you need to add _within the class_ not _within the constructor_

Comment: maybe start with some background in typescript/javascript https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: @suraj   if i want to do model instead of push means how can i achive that `this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);`

Comment: @suraj  i am struck with some more issue, here is that post stackoverflow.com/questions/43496455/… no solution found till now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`goToSomethingElse()` must be defined outside constructor. goToSomethingElse will be called whenever button is clicked

**Update**
Clear navigation stack/history when logout is pressed and user is redirected to login page.

1. Set login page as [root](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#setRoot) of the stack.
2. Clear all pages manually.

Try this

```
export class HomePage {

  slideData = [{ image: "assets/images/l1.png" },{ image: "assets/images/l2.png" },{ image: "assets/images/l3.png" }]


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {    
  }

  goToSomethingElse() {
      // Logout would be a better name in the given context

      // Set login page as root of the stack.
      this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);


      // OR clear all pages manually(comment above line is you are using this)
      this.nav.push(LoginPage).then(() => {
          const num = this.nav.length(); // Get number of pages in current stack
          this.nav.remove(0, num); // If this removes LoginPage also, use num -1
      });

   }

}
```

Github [issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5847)

Comment: thanks . i am struck with some more issue, here is that post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496455/how-to-show-pdf-file-in-ionic-app-with-out-download   no solution found till now

Comment: @sinha I dont have ionic setup right not. Will try out that later

Comment: if i want to do model instead of push means how can i achive that this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);

Comment: what does `model` means? Can you elaborate more. Edit question with more details

Comment: like if we do push it will come with back button . I want to redirect from one screen to another screen with out push. like if i redirect from home screen -----> to login screen. Then in my login screen i have two button at left and right nav bar. So i should not see back. It should open as model window of whole scren.